# How can I use function recalling in this code?

Tags: javascript, simplify

So basically I have been working on this challenge, where a function gets the number of cookies and plates as a parimeter and it has to calculate all the posibilities for the cookies to be destributed over the given amount of plates, where no plate can be empty.
And the possibilities are not allowed to be the same even if they are in a different order .e.g [1, 2, 3] [3, 1, 2]

```
function areEqual(array1, array2) {
  return array1.every((element, index) => {
    if (element === array2[index]) return true;
    else return false;
  });
}
console.log(areEqual([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]));

function divideCookies(cookies, plates) {
  // You have to implement this method
  // const possibilities = [];
  const plates2 = (cookies) => {
    const possibilities = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < Math.floor(cookies / 2) + 1; i++) {
      possibilities.push([i, cookies - i]);
    }
    return possibilities;
  };

  const plates3 = (cookies) => {
    const possibilities = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < Math.floor(cookies / 3) + 1; i++) {
      const x = plates2(cookies - i);
      console.log(x);
      x.forEach((plate) => {
        possibilities.push([i, ...plate]);
      });
    }
    for (const arr of possibilities) {
      arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    }

    possibilities.sort().forEach((el, i, arr) => {
      if (arr[i + 1]) {
        if (areEqual(el, arr[i + 1])) {
          possibilities.splice(possibilities.indexOf(el), 1);
        }
      }
    });
    return possibilities;
  };
  const plates4 = (cookies) => {
    const possibilities = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < Math.floor(cookies / 4) + 1; i++) {
      const x = plates3(cookies - i);

      x.forEach((plate) => {
        possibilities.push([i, ...plate]);
      });
    }
    for (const arr of possibilities) {
      arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    }

    possibilities.sort().forEach((el, i, arr) => {
      if (arr[i + 1]) {
        if (areEqual(el, arr[i + 1])) {
          possibilities.splice(possibilities.indexOf(el), 1);
        }
      }
    });
    return possibilities;
  };

  if (plates === 2) {
    const possibilities = plates2(cookies);
    return possibilities;
  } else if (plates === 3) {
    const possibilities = plates3(cookies);
    return possibilities;
  }
  if (plates === 4) {
    const possibilities = plates4(cookies);
    return possibilities;
  }
  if (plates === 5) {
    const possibilities = plates4(cookies);
    return possibilities;
  }
}
```

While writing this code I realized that there is a pattern, which makes it possible to drastically simplify this code and even make it possible to calculate the possibilities for any number of plates, but unfortunatly I don't really know how to do it.
I would really appreciate it if someone could take a bit of time to look over this code and tell me how it has to be done.

Comment: FYI, the term you used, *fonction recalling*, is called *recursion*.

Comment: `const areEqual = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.every((el, i) => arr2[i] === el);`